# Click on button inside canvas element

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, canvas, iframe

I would like to click on verify button that is embedded inside canvas element using jquery or selenium.
example

[image]

Please suggest me How i click inside canvas.

Comment: Can you show us the code you've written so far?https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Read through this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

Comment: I am using bellow code for facebook selenium webdriver.

$hover = $webdriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath("//*[@id='abc']//iframe"));
$webdriver->action()->moveToElement($hover)->moveByOffset(155, 195)->click()->perform();
Above code is not working.
Please suggest me how i click on verify button

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at easeljs, it's a JS library which gives you the option to select an area of the canvas to be clickable. https://createjs.com/getting-started/easeljs

Comment: Actually it is creating new layer on canvas then we are clickable on layer
But I need to click on existing verifying button draw inside canvas.
If i am wrong Please suggest me solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simple using the Canvate library.
http://www.sakuracode.com/canvate

You can use any image as Button (jpg, png, svg), even with irregular shapes using opacity.

Here you are an example.

```
container.startDrag();
```

https://codepen.io/EiseiKashi/pen/BxNbmj

You can add other listeners as: click, rollOVer, rollOut, mouseDown, mouseUp.

And more, you can add all the images as you want and animate them.

For any question, please let me know!